# Error uploading to esp 32 board

Tags: esp32

I had a problem when installing the esp32 core. I couldn't do it through the board manager procedure because I can't find esp32 for installation in the board manager even though I put the link correctly in the preferences section so I had to download a zip file and unzip it in hardware/espressif/esp32 folder. Now whenever I try to upload the code(a simple LED blinking code) it says error compiling for board with the following error message
exec: "C:\Users\ABDUL\Documents\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++: file does not exist
Please help me. I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: So does the file, C:\Users\ABDUL\Documents\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++, exist?

Comment: You know that, besides entering the link in the preferences section, you have to download and install the new board manager from the "Tools->Board XXX->Board Manager" menu, don't you?

Comment: what link is this? ... `I put the link correctly in the preferences section`

Comment: This link "https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json". I put it in preferences but I couldn't find the esp32 for installation in tools>boards>board manager. I searched as instructed but I couldn't find it

Comment: Sometimes it seems to help to close and reopen the IDE after editing the boards manager URLs list.

Comment: The correct link is `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json`

Comment: I just tried it. It's showing the same result as the previous one. It's not showing esp32 in the board manager

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the IDE or installing an older version?